# Error starting web application - Passenger, Rails, Raspberry PI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, raspberry-pi, passenger

I have a ROR app (version 6.1.4.1) with Ruby 2.7.4 on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB RAM and a 32 GB SD card. I installed Passenger 6.0.12 using the tarball installation and am running it with nginx. `passenger start` in the app directory works successfully, but when I try running it as with nginx (`/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`) on port 80, I get the above error when visiting the site.

I'm accessing the app via IP address, which is configured in the `nginx.conf` and the app is installed in `/home/pi/src/bogie_can`. There is a `.bundle` directory with a config file in the app directory, and that's where the gems are installed. I'm running the app in "development" mode, which is configured in the `server` section of the `nginx.conf` file using `passenger_app_env`.

The specific error is that the app cannot find `racc-1.5.2`. The Bundler info is `#<struct Bundler::Settings::Path explicit_path="/home/pi/src/bogie_can/.bundle", system_path=false, default_install_uses_path=false>.`. So, we note that the `.bundle` path is correct and in the `.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/` directory, `racc-1.5.2` is indeed installed and owned by the user "pi".

I've cleared out old bundle installations and tried switching the app user from `pi` to `root` (which was `nobody`) and back. Also, I'm using `rbenv`, so I also ran `rbenv rehash` after the fresh `bundle install`. I've also carefully reviewed the "Detailed diagnostics" from the Passenger error page (which is super helpful!) and do not see anything that is obviously wrong.

Using the Passenger error page as a guide, it seems that:

1. The gems are indeed installed as needed
2. The user, either root or pi, have permissions to access the gems
3. `pi` is a reasonable user to run the app
4. The `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` are coming from the `passenger-config about` subcommands and are verified as well.

At this point, there must be some configuration I've overlooked or gotten wrong and I would greatly appreciate some questions and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the problem.

I had set `passenger_ruby` to the result of `passenger-command about ruby-command`, which gave me:

```
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /usr/bin/ruby2.7
  Version: ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.7
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.7
  To use with Standalone: /usr/bin/ruby2.7 /usr/src/passenger-6.0.12/bin/passenger start

The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
  Command: /home/pi/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/pi/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/pi/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/pi/.rbenv/shims/ruby /usr/src/passenger-6.0.12/bin/passenger start
```

I was using `/usr/bin/ruby2.7` and having the problem with `racc` not being found. I switched it to use the rbenv shim and Passenger was able to correctly find all the gems in the `[APP_ROOT]/.bundle/` directory

I also cleared out the default nginx installation, which was still trying to be started with `nginx.service` and then added my own `/etc/init.d/nginx` script and added it to the `init.d` database so that it now starts with the OS.